# systemd-fsck failed with error code 8. Unable to repair disk on bootup

Tags: systemd, fsck

I have two partitions, one for the RO root filesystem (mmcblk3p1), and the other is the RW home partition (mmcblk3p2). I can't figure out why `systemd-fsck` is unable to fix my partition when I manually corrupt it with:

`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1000 of=/dev/mmcblk3p2 seek=1000`

I can repair my partition manually in under 5 seconds, so the issue must be inside of libsystemd-fsck

`e2fsck /dev/mmcblk3p2 -y`

My fstab is configured so that both partitions are checked upon bootup and the kernel config tells fsck to attempt a repair.

```
Kernel command line: console= consoleblank=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0 fsck.mode=auto fsck.repair=yes root=/dev/mmcblk3p1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait ro
```

It appears that fsck is receiving an immediate error when it attempts to repair during bootup. I can see the errors inside of my journal.

`journalctl | grep fsck`

```
Jan 02 21:43:05 systemd-fsck[192]: e2fsck 1.43-WIP (18-May-2015)
Jan 02 21:43:05 systemd-fsck[192]: /dev/mmcblk3p1: clean, 9287/192576 files, 139802/192512 blocks
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: e2fsck 1.43-WIP (18-May-2015)
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: /dev/mmcblk3p2: recovering journal
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: /dev/mmcblk3p2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: fsck: Warning... fsck.ext4 for device /dev/mmcblk3p2 exited with signal 13.
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: fsck failed with error code 8.
Jan 02 21:43:07 systemd-fsck[673]: Ignoring error.
Jan 02 21:43:07 kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk3p2): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
```

Signal 13 and error code 8 don't help me too much in digging into the root cause of the problem. The only other issue I could find online is [this one](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788050) from the Ubuntu Mailing lists, but it concerns a bug related to the systemd-fsck 30s timeout.

I'm using systemd-229 with 4.1.38 kernel which are dated, but it is what I have to work with.

EDIT: I ended up just making another service that ran e2fsck before the systemd-fsck@device one. This automatically solved any found issues and returned successfully.

```
[Unit]
Description=File System Check on /dev/mmcblk3p2
DefaultDependencies=no
BindsTo=dev-mmcblk3p2.device
After=dev-mmcblk3p2.device systemd-fsck-root.service local-fs-pre.target
Before=shutdown.target systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk3p2.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/e2fsck /dev/mmcblk3p2 -y
TimeoutSec=0
SuccessExitStatus=1 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I would change `grub`'s `fsck.mode=auto` to `fsck.mode=force`.